Is it possible to read incoming calls from laptop in C#?
I am trying to create a windows desktop application (C# .NET MAUI), that will show incoming calls on the screen, so that I can add other informations.
I've found Windows "Phone link" application, that seems to exactly what I need, but I was not able to find any library/documentation on how to access it.
I saw some other applications, but it seems that they work creating a new phone number over internet. My need instead, is to read the incoming calls of the already existing phone number of my customer (that will answer in his phone, I just need to have the information in the application).
Do you have any suggestion on how to read incoming phone calls from a desktop application?

What makes you believe there is an API? Phone Link looks like a standalone app, which connects to your phone app, both needs access to internet. It's not a part of anything (like Office) to be worth investing into automation, plugins, api, etc.
